# Function for bar plot in python

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to write an function for bar plot and it has to be like the plot shown below for `Category` and `Group` based on the index. The problem here is function has to divide `X` - `Index` and `Y` -`Index` separately and plot the graphs for `Category` and `Group`.

```
Index   Group   Category    Population
X       A       5           12
X       A       5           34
Y       B       5           23
Y       B       5           34
Y       B       6           33
X       A       6           44
Y       C       7           12
X       C       7           23
Y       A       8           12
Y       A       8           4
X       B       8           56
Y       B       9           67
X       B       10          23
Y       A       8           45
X       C       9           34
X       C       9           56
```

Here the `Men` and `Women` are `Index- X, Y` in my case
[image]

I have tried many different ways but not able to solve this issue. It would be really helpful if anyone would help me in this.

Comment: What are the "many different ways" you've tried, and how did they fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it's the easiest way to plot multi-indices IMP:

```
df["Index"] = df["Index"].map({"X":"Male", "Y": "Female"})
df_ = df.groupby(["Group","Category","Index"]).mean().unstack()
df_.plot.bar()
```

This will give you:

[image]